# jQuery positioning and appending a div on mouse move

Tags: jquery

Well i tried to do something like this :

```
var oldX=0,oldY=0;
$('body').mousemove(function(e){
     $('.movestatus').text('mouse moved');
     var clientCoords = "( " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY + " )";
     $(".chords").text(clientCoords);
     var ap = $("<div class='k'></div>");
     ap.offset({ top: e.clientX, left: e.clientY });
         $("body").append(ap);
     oldX = e.clientX;
     oldY = e.clientY;
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/nW53h/)

Well this works **BUT** the added div are added a lot below where the mouse actually is and also not added always.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: is the demo fiddle missing some HTML?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No. I left it empty deliberately.

Comment: @andy Something like u have a white board. Something close to it.

Comment: something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/nW53h/8/

Comment: @andy absolutely :). Except one thing. When i move the mouse too fast it doesnt adds them. Because mousemove misses it. Any way to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add  `position: absolute;` to you class `k`

AND

```
ap.offset({ top: e.clientX, left: e.clientY });
```

should be:

```
ap.offset({ top: e.clientY, left: e.clientX });
```

[**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nW53h/6/)

Comment: OH OH yea. Worked like a charm. Blind much me :)

Answer (score 1):

One little thing you forgot:

```
.k {
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute; <-------
}
```